# makedo without find() with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to use an equivalent to find(".class") in angularjs

I've found that I should use this:

```
//find('.classname'), assumes you already have the starting elem to search from
angular.element(elem.querySelector('.classname'))
```

So I'm trying in my directive but can't make it work:

```
UserManager.directive('selectWhenEditing',function(){
    var linkFunction = function(scope,startingelem,attributes)
    {

        console.log(angular.element(startingelem.querySelector('.classname')));

    };
    return{
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link:linkFunction
    };}
);
```

but that doesn't work it gives me

```
Error: startingelem.querySelector is not a function
```

what do I do wrong ?

Comment: simple use document.querySelector(selectors); element doesn't have a querySelector method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[element does have querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector), the element that is passed to the link function, `startingelem` in your case, is wrapped in jqLite.  Because of this, you don't have access to all of the attributes and functions attached to it.  You need to access the actual element/node to get access `querySelector`. You can do with with `startingelem[0]`

```
UserManager.directive('selectWhenEditing',function(){
    var linkFunction = function(scope,startingelem,attributes)
    {

        console.log(angular.element(startingelem[0].querySelector('.classname')));

    };
    return{
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link:linkFunction
    };}
);
```

Note the difference between `element.querySelector(...)` and `document.querySelector(...)` is the difference between `$('.myElement').find(...)` and `$(document).find(...)` where one looks in an particular element's children and the other looks at all of the element in the document.

Also to make it more similar to jQuery's find, you should use `querySelectorAll(...)` to find all of the elements that match. `querySelector(...)` would be more similar to `.find(...).first()`

Comment: angular.element(startingelem[0].querySelector('.classname')); vs document.querySelector('.classname'); does it make sense ?

Comment: querySelector on document finds the first one in the document, querySelector on element finds the first one within the element. the `angular.element` stuff just wraps it in jqLite, which was just taken from the example... So `startingelem[0].querySelector(...)` vs `document.querySelector('...')` can have different results.

Comment: good point but what about document.querySelector('.classname')[0] :)

Comment: @Whisher I don't think that does what you think that does.

Comment: you are right document.querySelector('.classname') returns the first element within the document
 so the good one is document.querySelectorAll('.classname')[0]

Comment: @TheSharpieOne sorry to bother you but I've a doubt is there a difference between angular.element(element) and simply element I mean I can use like element.find('div') instead of angular.element(element.find('div'))

Comment: `element.find('div')` will return a jquery/jqlite wrapped element, wrapping it again with `angular.element(...)` is not needed and essentially does nothing.  Keep in mind `element.find(...)` is limited to tag name lookup only (wih jqlite) so `div` will work in this case, `.classname` will not.

Answer (score 0):

`.querySelector()` is a method of `document`

Replace

```
startingelem.querySelector
```

**by**

```
document.querySelector()
```